# Is it possible to insert wrong info in the MsSql database when we use transactions

Tags: sql-server

So Theoretically is it possible to insert information partially in the database when we use transactions. For example the insert happens and suddenly we lose electricity. Will there be a case when one record will be written to tableA and it wouldn't be written to tableB?

Comment: If someone answers yes, we're screwed... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self explained in [begin transaction manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx):

> If errors are encountered, all data modifications made after the BEGIN
>   TRANSACTION can be rolled back to return the data to this known state
>   of consistency.

The answer is no: it is not possible. For your scenario, is TableA and TableB inserts are both in same transaction, due to ACID behavior, if 'lose electricity' occurs between inserts, when database go up, TableA insert is rolled back. Remember the A of atomic.

Answer (score 0):

It will not happen, because of all activities are all first written to transaction log, not to the actual data files, and in case of electricity failure, when sql server starts it will go through transaction log and rollback any unfinished transactions ( you will notice how slow it starts or database will be in recovery mode for a while ).

Data files are written to by writers after some period of time, before that memory is available in memory as dirty pages.